# facebook javascript pass image parameter with multiple values

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook javascript sdk and graph api.my code is workin fine with single image.how to pass multi value parameter to image.

```
 $("#ac").click(function() 
{
   FB.init({
    appId      : 'validappid',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });   
  FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
       var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
       console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
       FB.api('me/posimplicity:eat',
          'post',
          {
            restaurant: "http://samples.ogp.me/440002909390231",
             image:'http://abc.in/images/items/120px-Chana_masala.jpg',
          },
          function(response) {console.log(response);
            // handle the response
          }
        );
    }  
 },{scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos'});
 })
 (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BJK2b/33/
I want to show the all dishes images that ordered

Comment: Have you tried simply passing an array of image URLs …?

Comment: Yes I tried but not working